# my desktop icons (PC) disappeared

Tags: windows-7, windows, desktop

I was using my win7 PC, and all the sudden most of my desktop icons disappeared.
I searched for an item I remembered and I saw it's in the temp Recycle bin. I have tried to open this path (`open path`), but didn't see my item there as if it was hidden.

How can I bring the icons back?

[image]

Comment: AFAIK, back in the XP days, you had to check if `explorer.exe` was running. This also hid the taskbar, so it could be something else.

Comment: i meant expore path command. not explorer.exe

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear if your 'explorer.exe' has stopped or your desktop icons have simply disappeared. Is the taskbar (start menu's bar) visible?

If your explorer has stopped,
go to task manager (control + alt + delete) --> Go to NEW TASK --> click BROWSE --> paste C:\Windows\explorer.exe on the path bar.

If your icons have disappeared right click your start menu and choose the icons you want on your desktop.

If your icons have been hidden,
on an explorer window,
click Organise --> folder and search options --> View menu --> Select the 'SHOW HIDDEN FILES AND FOLDERS' and click apply.

Comment: i meant expore path command. not explorer.exe

Comment: You mean the RIGHT CLICK --> EXPLORE command?

Comment: I meant I tried to open the foler which is circled in red

Comment: Open run and type %temp% and search for your file there. If its not there, try temp or prefetch in run.

Comment: not there...I have tried now

Comment: What do you basically want to do? Bring your icons back or access the file in the recycle bin?

Comment: bring the icons back

Comment: To see the icons, try the solution i mentioned in my answer.